# ASP.NET Core MVC : loading nupkg file and use it at run time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, runtime, nuget-package

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project, and I want to load a file of type `.nupkg` at runtime, with a different version every time, and use the code from the loaded file.

The nuget file exists in a different project.

How do I do that?

The nuget source:

[image]